# Drafting SQL search query based on user entry

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently coding a simple search script in PHP that requires three variables from the user namely:
**$Capacity**, **$Location** and **$RoomType**

**Capacity** is a required field which the jquery validate plugin checks for numerical entry on input - but **Location** and **RoomType** are optional.

I'm trying to now draft a SQL query that will search the table **rooms**.

There are three columns in the table also called **Capacity**, **Location** and **RoomType** that I want to search using the variables.

How would I write this SQL query? Especially with **$Capacity** being required, **$Location** / **$RoomType** expected to be left blank or filled in at the users discretion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `LIKE ...%` in your sql query, so that even when blank, it'll be treated as a wildcard.

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE capacity = "'.$capacity.'" AND location LIKE "'.$location.'%" AND roomtype LIKE "'.$roomtype.'%"';
```

Of course, remember to escape the inputs.

Comment: How do I check whether the Capacity variable is in a specific range for example if the user types in 50 then the entry in the table is 100 then it falls in range?

Comment: In php, you can add `$capacityA = $capacity - 50; $capacityB = $capacity + 50;` and in MySQL change it to `WHERE capacity BETWEEN $capacityA AND $capacityB`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
function BuildSearchQuery($Capacity, $Location, $RoomType)
{

    $where = array();

    if (!empty($Capacity))
    {
        $where[] = "Capacity = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($Capacity) . "'";
    }
    if (!empty($Location))
    {
        $where[] = "Location = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($Location) . "'";
    }
    if (!empty($RoomType))
    {
        $where[] = "RoomType = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($RoomType) . "'";
    }

    if (empty($where))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $sql = "select * from `table` where ";
    $sql += implode(" AND ", $where);

    return $sql;

}
```

Although nowadays many frameworks exists that allow you to do this more easily and less error-prone than manually crafting queries.

Comment: I'm using Dreamweaver can you recommend any that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

$query =select * from table where Capacity =$Capacity

if(isset($Location) && $Location!='') $query.= and Location  LIKE '%$location%'

if(isset($RoomType) && $RoomType!='') $query.= and RoomType LIKE '%$RoomType%'

Making use of LIKE or = operator in query is upto you.

Comment: `if(isset($Location) && $Location!='')` is equivalent to `if(!empty($location))`

Answer (score 0):

Depend on how complex it is (and or not ???)

But basically

```
Select ... From Rooms Where Capacity = @Capacity 
and ((Location = @Location) Or (IsNull(@Location,'') = '')) 
and ((RoomType = @RoomType) or (IsNull(@RoomType,'') = ''))
```

Or some such.

If you aren't using parameterised queryies then replace @.... with the escaped inputs.